# Как убрать повторяющиеся код?

Tags: python, инспекция-кода, простые-числа

Есть код который находит все просты числа от `2` до `n`. Он работает нормально но мне не нравится что в нем есть почти два одинаковых `if`. Как их убрать и при этом не увеличить время работы функции?

```
def f(n):
    set_ = set()
    arr = [2, 3]
    for i in range(6, n+1, 6):
        a, b = i - 1, i + 1

        if a not in set_:
            set_.update(range(a, n+1, a))
            arr.append(a)
        if b not in set_:
            set_.update(range(b, n+1, b))
            arr.append(b)

    return arr
```

Comment: Какой-то извращённый вариант решета Эратосфена. Ваше решение работает быстрее классической реализации?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов да, моё решение гораздо быстрее обычной реализации

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Как вариант, использовать цикл `for`:

```
def f(n):
    set_ = set()
    arr = [2, 3]
    for i in range(6, n+1, 6):
        for var in (i-1, i+1):
            if var not in set_:
                set_.update(range(var, n+1, var))
                arr.append(var)
    return arr
```

2. Генератор, если вдруг понадобиться:

```
def gen_f(n):
   yield 2
   yield 3
   set_ = set()
   for i in range(6, n+1, 6):
       for var in (i-1, i+1):
           if var not in set_:
               set_.update(range(var, n+1, var))
               yield var
   return None
```

3. Однако вывод вашей функции не совсем соответсвует описанию:

```
n, f(n)
0 [2, 3] # 2 > 0 and 3 > 0
1 [2, 3] # 2 > 1 and 3 > 1
2 [2, 3] # 2 == 2 and 3 > 2
3 [2, 3] # 3 == 3
4 [2, 3]
5 [2, 3]
6 [2, 3, 5, 7] # 7 > 6
7 [2, 3, 5, 7] # 7 == 7
8 [2, 3, 5, 7] 
9 [2, 3, 5, 7] 
...
```

4. Этот код уберет первые 2 ошибочных вывода:

```
def f1(n):
    arr = []
    for m in (2, 3):
        if n < m:
            return arr
        arr.append(m)
    set_ = set()
    for i in range(6, n+1, 6):
        for var in (i-1, i+1):
            if var not in set_:
                set_.update(range(var, n+1, var))
                arr.append(var)
    return arr
```

Comment: какие числа он ещё находит, можно пример входных данных при котором выдаются не простые числа?

Comment: @Danis, извиняюсь. подумал почему-то, что 29 - не простое. уберу замечание.

Comment: @Danis добавил новую придирку )

Comment: это особо не критично

Comment: я тоже могу к вам придраться. Ваш код увеличил время работы

Comment: @Danis тот, который убирает выводы ? - ну да. тут другого и не ожидалось. добавил еще генератор, если вдруг понадобиться

Comment: нет самый первый с циклом for

Comment: @Danis, у меня на тестах он показывал увеличение быстродействия. Но, похоже, что не получиться убрать повтор кода, не потеряв при этом скорость.

Comment: ещё раз перепроверил и ваш код медлее. мой примерно за `2.0` а ваш за `2.2`.

Comment: @Danis, странно. но ладно. все же нет варианта сокращения без потери производительности, похоже.

Comment: @Danis А вы куда-то торопитесь, извините? Я понимаю, если речь о сервере, который обслуживает миллионы запросов, но это же явно какая-то разовая задача, зачем тут вообще заниматься оптимизацией, если, конечно, разница в скорости не на порядок, что было бы, конечно, нехорошо. )

Answer (score 3):

Ну вынести в функцию общие действия - стандартный же рефакторинг:

```
def f_update(arr, set_, x, n):
    if x not in set_:
        set_.update(range(x, n+1, x))
        arr.append(x)

def f(n):
    set_ = set()
    arr = [2, 3]
    for i in range(6, n+1, 6):
        a, b = i - 1, i + 1

        f_update(arr, set_, a, n)
        f_update(arr, set_, b, n)

    return arr
```

Comment: да хорошая идея, но есть одно но, из-за того что каждый раз приходится вызывать функцию, время работы основной функции увеличилось

Comment: @Danis Ну, всё зависит от того, сколько раз вызывается функция, сколько раз срабатывает if. Если время настолько критично и if часто не срабатывает, то можно попробовать if не выносить.

Comment: если вынести `if` в основу функцию, то работает быстрее но все равно дольше чем изначальная версия. Мне кажется здесь в коде либо красиво но медленно, либо быстрее но менее красиво